# How to plot a bessel-like function in MATLAB 

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm totally new to MATLAB and I know only few basic commands. My task is to plot a function of this kind:

```
I(T) = ((2*J(k*r*sin(T))/(k*r*sin(T))))^2
```

where

```
T = angle

k = (2*pi*f)/c   (f= frequency in Hz and c is speed of sound)

r = radius

J = bessel function first kind
```

I explain a bit: the function represent the power of a soundwave in the space. I've tried many times to plot this but i get always a single point in the plot.

Comment: How do you define your `T` and `r`? Are they vectors?

Comment: Maybe start with the Matlab Tutorial? http://www.mathworks.com/academia/student_center/tutorials/launchpad.html

Answer (score 3):

I assume you've defined your Bessel function in `J`. If not, the MATLAB command for a Bessel function of the first kind is `besselj`. You'll also have to specify the order of the Bessel function.

You can define your anonymous function as

```
f=@(t,k,r)(2*besselj(0,k*r*sin(t))./(k*r*sin(t))).^2
```

and plot it as

```
T=linspace(0,pi,100);%# a sample angle vector
plot(T,f(T,k,r))     %# where k and r are values you'll have to provide
```

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
I = ((2*J(k*r*sin(T))./(k*r*sin(T)))).^2
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to manage the problem described above, here's the solution that i found, in case that other people may need it.

% MATLAB Istruction for graph generation of bessel like function %
% Variables (fixed values)%
k = 912.91
r = 0.0215

% Set the range for the angle theta %
theta = (-(2/3)*pi:pi/180:(2/3)*pi)

% Calculation of bessel function of first kind %
J = besselj(1,k*r*sin(theta))

% Calculation I function %
% notice the ./ and .^ operators
I = ((2*J)./(k*r*sin(theta))).^2

% now plot the results with the plot command
plot(theta,I)